# what to do with your bin directory

Tags: organization, directory-structure

To get off my noob status i am following the [Learn python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org) course.

I really like it but at one point it says make a bin directory. In all games and other programs i saw to a bin directory but what does it do?

Comment: Typically the `bin` directory is for binaries, which are output by the compiler

Comment: Sounds like a good place to put your .exe files if you use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: @Fred: One normally puts python scripts to be executed to bin as well.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know in what context it was mentioned in the course, but the ***bin*** directory is usually (almost always) where the binaries/executable files are located.

It is the directory which usually doesn't go under source control, and gets rewritten every time upon each new build.

*I hold no sentimental value towards it.*